# Swig enum using values from other library

Tags: c#, c++, enums, wrapper, swig

I would like to use Swig to generate C# wrappers for my c++ classes. I am facing the following problem:

I have defined an enum that uses values from a third party (closed source) library.
The values are declared inside HEADER_FROM_3RD_PARTY_LIB.h as

```
#define 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_1 -4
#define 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_1 -10
```

My header file looks like:

```
#include "HEADER_FROM_3RD_PARTY_LIB.h"

namespace Foo
{
    namespace Bar
   {    
    class MyClass
    {       
     public:    
            enum MyEnum
        {           
        Enum1 = 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_1,            
        Enum2 = 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_2     
        };
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the following swig code:

```
%module cpp  

%{  
    #include "MyClass.h"  
%}  

%include <windows.i>  
%include "MyClass.h"
```

The wrapper is successfully generated but the generated csharp file has the following enum generated:

```
public enum MyEnum
{           
    Enum1 = 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_1,            
    Enum2 = 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_2     
}
```

Obviously this generates an error since C# cannot find the 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_1 and 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_2 values.

Any ideas who could this be resolved? I had a look at Swig examples but could not find something similar.

Comment: That's rather odd. Have you tried building MyClass.cpp and it builds fine? The 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONSTs are they anoter enum, or a #define, or static const or what? Please update your question not in comment.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I have updated my question and provided a temporary solution, but I am not happy with the result.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found so far was either to include

```
#include "HEADER_FROM_3RD_PARTY_LIB.h"
```

in the swig file or redefine the values again in the swig file

```
#define 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_1 -4
#define 3RD_PARTY_LIB_CONST_VALUE_1 -10
```

Any other suggestions how this could be improved? The problem with the first approach is that by including the entire header file I get lots of auto generated files that I do not need.

Comment: I agree, but +1 for finding a solution and posting it.